# Incompatiple type when use generic at both class and method

Tags: java, generic-programming

Here I have class use generic

```
public class ParamsContainer <E extends Enum<E> & Param>
{
  protected Map<E, Object> params;

  public <T> T getWithType(E param) {
    return (T) params.get(param);
  }
}
```

Here I got failed type checking from compiler.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar rqDateTime = paramsContainer.getWithType(Param.SYS_RATES_DATE);
```

Could you help why I get the message 
"Incompatiple types. 
 Require: XMLGregorianCalendar
 found: Object"

Answer (score 1):

`protected Map<E, Object> params;` the value is an object so hence an object

so you can try casting to convert an object to `XMLGregorianCalendar`

```
XMLGregorianCalendar rqDateTime = (XMLGregorianCalendar)paramsContainer.getWithType(Param.SYS_RATES_DATE);
```

Comment: I know this solution but the point is I don't want to cast out side.

Comment: @MaiHữuLợi then buddy you have to cast it inside your implementation by changing the return type and returned value(thorough cast) to `XMLGregorianCalendar ` or simple use explicit Type( nicolas  e.g )to provide the cast during invocation

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is the related to the fact that the value of your `Map` is of type `Object`, you should use a more specific type.

However if you know that the value will be of type `XMLGregorianCalendar`, you could simply rely on **the type parameter** `T` that you defined in the definition of your method `getWithType` and solve it as next:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar rqDateTime = 
    paramsContainer.<XMLGregorianCalendar>getWithType(Param.SYS_RATES_DATE);
```

More details about generic methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).

Comment: Normaly if I don't apply generic to class `<E extends Enum<E> & Param>`, then it is working well. But thanks. this is a good solution so far.

Comment: For me,  `<E extends Enum<E> & Param>` is not related to your current issue, if it worked before it was due to something else

Comment: I use IntelliJ. I have double check already. You can try with your IDE and see result.

Comment: And what do you put to replace `E` in your map ?

Comment: XMLGregorianCalendar, String, Integer ... any `type` may come up when using the API `public void set(E param, Object value) {
    params.put(param, value);
  }`

Comment: Sorry, you mean the key! `paramsContainer.getWithType(Param.SYS_RATES_DATE);` You see it is an Enum value.